# Create query with dynamic columns from different tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I'm trying to create a query with dynamic columns, based on data from three tables.

This is the database structure:

**STUDENT**

- `studentID int`,
- `studentNumber int`,
- `studentName nvarchar(100)`.

**EXAM:**

- `examID int`,
- `examName varchar(100)`,
- `examenDate datetime`,

**EXAM_REGISTRATION:**

- `studentID int`,
- `examID int`,

A record is added to the `EXAM_REGISTRATION` table when a student has registered for an exam.

What I'm trying to get is a list of all the exams and all the students in a pivot table to see which students have registered for which exams, like this:

[image]

Quite frankly I don't know where to start.

I can query everything individually and put it all together but how can I combine it into one query?

I've been researching pivot tables, but every example seems to query only from one table and uses numbers and functions like `MIN`, `AVG` etc.

Can someone help me along?

Comment: is it possible for a student to take exam twice ?

Comment: No, that will be a newly scheduled exam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok lets go

some data to play with

```
create table #student
(studentID int, studentNumber int, studentName nvarchar(100))
create table #exam 
(examID int, examName nvarchar(100), examDate datetime)
create table #examReg
(studentID int, examID int)

insert into #student
values (1, 787878, 'pierwszy')
,(2, 89898, 'drugi')
,(3, 343434, 'trzeci')
,(4, 121212, 'czwarty')

insert into #exam
values (1, 'exPierwszy', GETDATE())
,(2, 'exDrugi', GETDATE())
,(3, 'exTrzeci', GETDATE())

insert into #examReg
values (1,2),(1,3)
, (2,2),(2,3)
,(3,1),(3,2)
,(4,1),(4,2),(4,3)
```

and now the main part, and explanation

first of all you have to get pivot query

```
select examName, examDate , min([1])  , min([2]), min([3]) ,min([4])--studentID as studentID, examDate --,studentNumber
from 
(select a.studentID , studentNumber, examDate, examName
from #student a 
join #examReg b on a.studentID = b.studentID
join #exam c on c.examID = b.examID ) as m
pivot
(min(studentNumber) FOR studentID in ([1],[2],[3],[4])) as t
group by examName, examDate
```

as you have it , just change it select statement and studentID list in pivot declaration, you have to generate those parts dynamicly , so we just copy previously written query and replace columns with our token

```
    declare @sqlTemplate nvarchar(max) = 
    'select examName, examDate @@sqlColumnList@@
    from 
    (select a.studentID , studentNumber, examDate, examName
    from #student a 
    join #examReg b on a.studentID = b.studentID
    join #exam c on c.examID = b.examID ) as m
    pivot
    (min(studentNumber) FOR studentID in (@@sqlStudentIDList@@)) as t
    group by examName, examDate
'
```

after that you generate column list and studentID list by concatenting strings in tsql

```
declare @sqlColumnList nvarchar(max) = ''
select @sqlColumnList += ',min([' + cast(studentID as nvarchar(10)) + ']) as [' + studentName +'(' + cast(studentNumber as nvarchar(10)) + ')]'
from #student
declare @sqlStudentIDList nvarchar(max) = ''
select @sqlStudentIDList += '[' + CAST(studentID as nvarchar(10)) + '],'
from #student

set @sqlStudentIDList = SUBSTRING(@sqlStudentIDList, 0, LEN(@sqlStudentIDList))
select @sqlStudentIDList
```

once you have it , all you have to do is to replace tokens in previous template

```
set @sqlTemplate = REPLACE(@sqlTemplate, '@@sqlColumnList@@', @sqlColumnList)
set @sqlTemplate = REPLACE(@sqlTemplate, '@@sqlStudentIDList@@', @sqlStudentIDList)


select @sqlTemplate

exec sp_executesql @sqlTemplate
```

and thats it 
if you want to read more about pivot go for msdn 
if you want to read about dynamic go for [this link](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

edit: to adjust the query for the question from comment you would have to change @sqlColumnList like that

```
select @sqlColumnList += ',min(' + QUOTENAME(studentID)  + ') as Student' + CAST(studentID as nvarchar(10))  + '_REG,
'''+ studentName + ''' as Student' + cast(studentID as nvarchar(10)) + '_NAME,
'+ cast(studentID as nvarchar(10)) + ' as Student' + cast(studentID as nvarchar(10)) + '_ID'
from #student
```

Comment: Great, the downside of getting something working: management wants more! :p
Now my supervisor asked to change it so the output is something like this: 
http://chieljan.net/download/Pivot2.png.

Is this even remotely possible with this query?

Comment: i dont know if you ve noticed i ve added an edit to the post regarding you second problem , just let know if it is what you are looking for , you just have to change @sqlColumnList

Comment: Yes, I was just looking at that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a *pivot* of the data. I would perform this slightly different than the other answer. If you know all of the values, then you can hard-code the values.

A static version will be:

```
select examname,
  examendate,
  IsNull([Smith, John (14323)], 'false') [Smith, John (14323)],
  IsNull([Craft, Peter (14334)], 'false') [Craft, Peter (14334)],
  IsNull([Davis, Alan (13432)], 'false') [Davis, Alan (13432)],
  IsNull([Newman, Ted (133123)], 'false') [Newman, Ted (133123)]
from
(
  select e.examname,
    e.examenDate,
    s.studentName + ' ('+cast(s.studentnumber as varchar(50))+')' studentNameNum,
    'true ' as Flag
  from exam e
  left join exam_registration er
    on e.examid = er.examid
  right join student s
    on er.studentid = s.studentid
) src
pivot
(
  max(flag)
  for studentNameNum in ([Smith, John (14323)], [Craft, Peter (14334)],
                      [Davis, Alan (13432)], [Newman, Ted (133123)])
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/72076/14)

If your values are unknown then the query will be:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsNull AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(s.studentName + ' ('+cast(s.studentnumber as varchar(50))+')') 
                    from student s
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

select @colsNull = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',IsNull(' + QUOTENAME(s.studentName + ' ('+cast(s.studentnumber as varchar(50))+')')+', ''false'')'+' as '+QUOTENAME(s.studentName+' ('+cast(s.studentnumber as varchar(50))+')') 
                    from student s
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT examname,
                  examenDate,' + @colsNull + ' from 
             (
                select e.examname,
                  e.examenDate,
                  s.studentName + '' (''+cast(s.studentnumber as varchar(50))+'')'' studentNameNum,
                  ''true '' as Flag
                from exam e
                left join exam_registration er
                  on e.examid = er.examid
                right join student s
                  on er.studentid = s.studentid
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(flag)
                for studentNameNum in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/72076/35)

The result will be:

```
| EXAMNAME |          EXAMENDATE | CRAFT, PETER (14334) | DAVIS, ALAN (13432) | NEWMAN, TED (133123) | SMITH, JOHN (14323) |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   Exam 1 | 2013-01-01 12:00:00 |                false |               false |                true  |               false |
|   Exam 2 | 2013-01-01 14:00:00 |                true  |               false |                false |               true  |
|   Exam 3 | 2013-01-02 12:00:00 |                true  |               true  |                false |               false |
|   Exam 4 | 2013-01-02 14:00:00 |                false |               false |                true  |               false |
|   Exam 5 | 2013-01-03 12:00:00 |                false |               false |                false |               true  |
```